# Failed to compare images with Imagemagick with robot framework on Windows environment

Tags: imagemagick, robotframework

I am using Imagemagick to compare two screenshots in windows environment.

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/09/robot-framework-compare-images-screenshots/

```
   *** Settings ***
Library   String
Library   OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND}   C:\\"Program Files"\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\\convert.exe


*** Test Cases ***
Image Comparison Ok
  Compare Images    C:/Users/user/imagecompare/Test/src/reference-screenshots/reference-1.png    C:/Users/user/imagecompare/Test/src/test-screenshots/test-1.png   0.1


Image Comparison NOk
  Compare Images    C:/Users/user/imagecompare/Test/src/reference-screenshots/reference-1.png    C:/Users/user/imagecompare/Test/src/test-screenshots/test-1.png   0.1

*** Keywords ***
Compare Images
   [Arguments]      ${Reference_Image_Path}    ${Test_Image_Path}    ${Allowed_Threshold}
   ${TEMP}=         Replace String     ${IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND}    __REFERENCE__     ${Reference_Image_Path}
   ${COMMAND}=      Replace String     ${TEMP}    __TEST__     ${Test_Image_Path}
   Log              Executing: ${COMMAND}
   ${RC}            ${OUTPUT}=     Run And Return Rc And Output     ${COMMAND}
   Log              Return Code: ${RC}
   Log              Return Output: ${OUTPUT}
   ${RESULT}        Evaluate    ${OUTPUT} < ${Allowed_Threshold}
   Should be True   ${RESULT}
```

But getting the following issue:

```
    KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log Return Output: ${OUTPUT}
Documentation:  
Logs the given message with the given level.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20171016 15:45:38.561 / 20171016 15:45:38.562 / 00:00:00.001
15:45:38.561    INFO    Return Output: The system cannot find the path specified.   
00:00:00.003KEYWORD ${RESULT} = BuiltIn . Evaluate ${OUTPUT} < ${Allowed_Threshold}
Documentation:  
Evaluates the given expression in Python and returns the results.
Start / End / Elapsed:  20171016 15:45:38.562 / 20171016 15:45:38.565 / 00:00:00.003
15:45:38.563    FAIL    Evaluating expression 'The system cannot find the path specified. < 0.1' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the *"legacy"* `convert` command with ImageMagick v7, you need to click the option during installation of **ImageMagick** that says *"Install legacy tools"*.

[image]

Or, use the new command which is:

```
magick input.png ... output.png
```

rather than:

```
convert input.png ... output.png
```

So, if you know how to change your configuration variable `IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND` to `C:\\"Program File"\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\\magick`, you can do it without re-installing ImageMagick.

Comment: Its not working i tried above solution and for your kind information i already  installed legacy utility (Converter)

Comment: Please check the path in your `IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND` - it is normally `C:\\Program FileSSSS...`

Comment: Below is the path for IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND  C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16

Comment: That's  not what you show in your settings above - you appear to have missed the `s` on `Program Files`.

Comment: Corrected variable name but still facing issue -->By default, the image format of 'file' is determined by its magic
number.  To specify a particular image format, precede the filename
with an image format name and a colon (i.e. ps:image) or specify the
image type as the filename suffix (i.e. image.ps).  Specify 'file' as
'-' for standard input or output. < 0.1' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Comment: What is the `0.1` at the end of the line that starts *"Compare Images"*?

Comment: Have you got spaces in your filenames? If so, surround the filenames with double quotes? Have you got the correct directory path separators - they look odd because Windows normally uses a backslash not a forwards slash? Should you maybe use double backslashes between directories rather than single forward slashes?

Comment: Basically 0.1 is Allowed_Threshold, You can refer below link for more information. I am using windows environment.  Also there is no space exists in filename and path.                        https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/09/robot-framework-compare-images-screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

${IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND}   C:/"Program Files"/ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16/convert.exe **REFERENCE** **TEST** -metric RMSE -compare -format  "%[distortion]" info:

replace with above IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND with suitable changes for your path.
It worked for me.
Thanks