# ImageMagick:: Throwing DLL error --> IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: imagemagick, robotframework, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to run a simple comparison ROBOT FrameWork Script. Here is the script..

```
    *** Settings ***
Library   String
Library   OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND}     D:\\"Program Files"\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\\convert __REFERENCE__ __TEST__ -metric RMSE -compare -format  "%[distortion]" info:

*** Test Cases ***
Image Comparison Ok
  Compare Images    D:/Project/Lg/imageCompare/CollectorCreation_IE.png    D:/Project/Lg/imageCompare/CollectorCreation_Chrome.png #  0.1


#Image Comparison NOk
#  Compare Images    D:/Project/Lg/imageCompare/CollectorCreation_IE.png    D:/Project/Lg/imageCompare/CollectorCreation_Chrome.png   0.1

*** Keywords ***
Compare Images
   [Arguments]      ${Reference_Image_Path}    ${Test_Image_Path}    ${Allowed_Threshold}
   ${TEMP}=         Replace String     ${IMAGE_COMPARATOR_COMMAND}    __REFERENCE__     ${Reference_Image_Path}
   log  ${TEMP}
   ${COMMAND}=      Replace String     ${TEMP}    __TEST__     ${Test_Image_Path}
   log  ${COMMAND}
   Log              Executing: ${COMMAND}
   ${RC}            ${OUTPUT}=     Run And Return Rc And Output     ${COMMAND}
   Log              Return Code: ${RC}
   Log              Return Output: ${OUTPUT}
   ${RESULT}        Evaluate    ${OUTPUT} < ${Allowed_Threshold}
   Should be True   ${RESULT}
```

but I ran into issue with dll's. Not sure what is the issue.

```
Return Output: convert: unable to load module 'd:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': The specified module could not be found.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1275.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: unable to load module 'd:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': The specified module could not be found.
 @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1275.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: unable to open image '#': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3323.
convert: unable to open image '#': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3323.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
convert: no images defined `info:' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3275.
```

I could see this dll in the given location bt program is not able to pick.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit machine and i installed "ImageMagick-7.0.7-14-Q16-x64-dll.exe" and got above issue and tried with "ImageMagick-7.0.7-14-Q8-x64-dll.exe" (i am picking from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)) same result.

Can some one help me out with issue. I am guessing it would be issue with the installed version.

```
C:\Users\bbanduch>magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-14 Q8 x64 2017-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

Comment: I do not know ROBOT, but ImageMagick 7 requires the use of magick rather than convert, unless you have loaded the legacy components when installing. Also does `magick -version` show PNG as a delegate library?

Comment: Have you had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773762/failed-to-compare-images-with-imagemagick-with-robot-framework-on-windows-enviro) and it's answers. It appears that you're folliowing a [CodeCentric.de tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/09/robot-framework-compare-images-screenshots/).

Comment: Hi, @A.Kootstra thx for  your support, Yes i tried to reuse CodeCentric tutorial. I have seen that Q before, there he was having issues with the path. which I crossed. but facing issue while loading DLL's

Comment: @fmw42 thx for your time. Yes i installed the Legacy components. Also PNG is part of delegate library.. here is the full screen ..C:\Users\bbanduch>magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-14 Q8 x64 2017-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: If you can run your ImageMagick command in a terminal and it works fine, the I would look at your other components for errors. Or perhaps you need to put your path to ImageMagick convert into your environmental variable for these other tools so that they can find ImageMagick. Perhaps it is as simple as including the full path to convert into your command.

Comment: Both "ImageMagick-7.0.7-14-Q16-x64-dll.exe" and "ImageMagick-7.0.7-14-Q8-x64-dll.exe" installations added path by default.  so path wise its good.  for e.g. i am able to compare command line ..{
D:\Project\Lg\imageCompare>compare Chrome.png IE.png  compare.png} above command gave me proper output